# nginx $host variable on AWS is incorrect

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I want to redirect http requests to https on and AWS EC2 instance running nginx. I tried this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
}
```

This fails since when I have this url originally:

```
http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com/some/uri/
```

It gets redirected to:

```
https://compute.amazonaws.com/some/uri/
```

Which implies that the variable $host has the value `compute.amazonaws.com`, which is not helpful for me. I need to access `ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com`.

I do not want to hardcode the url, like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.rr-rrrr-r.compute.amazonaws.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

since I am giving the AMI of the instance to someone else for them to use, so the hostname will change and be whatever they choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the instance knows its public hostname. But you can query it from the instance at the start using the following endpoint ([from docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)):

```
curl -l http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname
```

Then you can save it to a variable yourself and use it in the configuration.